# Rubberband effect on UIScrollView when content subview is scrolled up off screen

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, rubber-band

Not sure it's possible, but I have a scrollview with a bunch of subviews for content. When a particular subview is scrolled to and begins getting scrolled up off screen, I'd like to create the 'rubberband' effect, where the scrolling off screen becomes incrementally less as the scrolling continues (eventually after some threshold, the rubberband would 'snap', and the user would get past that particular subview. For now just focusing on the first part.)

My current attempt is to reset the contentOffset when the view's top goes above top of the scrollview, with a smaller distance between the scrollview top and subview:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > _myview.frame.origin.y) {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, _myview.frame.origin.y + ((scrollView.contentOffset.y - _myview.frame.origin.y) * .7))];
  }
}
```

When running it, the subview 'sticks' to the top of the scrollview, never going past, and not having the rubberband effect. Any thoughts or suggestions? Is this even possible? Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve your problem. If you find my answer help you out then can you accept and upvote please